# Axios returning 404 on laravel api request

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, axios

ive a write a code to send a get request to server using vue js.but it return 404 not found exception thought the route is created on laravel.

[image]

```
axios.get('/api/v1/companies')
                .then(function (resp) {
                    app.companies = resp.data;
                })
                .catch(function (resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                    alert("Could not load companies");
                });
```

route file :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' => 'api.', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::resource('companies', 'CompaniesController', ['except' => ['create', 'edit']]);
});
```

Comment: Your route group is just `/v1`, don't you mean `/api/v1`?

Comment: yes.but /api/v1 returning 404

Comment: Where have you defined `/api` route group encompassing `/v1`?